# Display Horizontal Bar Chart as below Image using MPAndroidChart Library

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

[image: I want to display Horizontal Bar as displayed in image using MPChart Library for Android]

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), I am able to draw Chart with Single Value on x-axis and y-axis with Positive values but not able to display as per image.

My code for Displaying Horizontal Bar Graph as following:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        xVals.add(mMonths[i % 12]);
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry((float) (Math.random() * 50), i));
    }

    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "DataSet 1");
```

Here what i have done that i am taking single value as x-axis and multiple values from 0 to 50  as random for displaying y-axis value.

Please Help me and Thanks In Advance as i am working with this scenario with 3 to 4 days but not able to do like image.

Comment: How to display the bold vertical line in bar chart as above displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a **stacked entry**, and assign both stack values the same color (making them appear as only one bar).

```
// create stacked bar-entry
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(new float[] {-30, 5}, xIndex);
```

Assign the same color for all values:

```
barDataSet.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

More info on stacked bars in the [example project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivityNegative.java).

Comment: Thanks @Philipp Jahoda i am able to draw chart as i want but i have to do to dra a chart horizontal bar anim from -30 to +30 in graph.

Comment: Hi Please check this question If your are able to help on this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993579/customized-line-chart-of-mpchart-library-android

Comment: Now I am able to make a Alarm Area using Custom your code.